# Why Python if statement is always returning True?

Tags: python, if-statement, return

I have this code:

```
while no_questions < 10:
    # Creating question and random values
    question = ""  # Blanking the question for continues use of one variable
    num1 = randint(1, 10); num2 = randint(1, 10); op = choice(operators)
    question = op(num1, num2)
    real_answer = question
    # Change operator to string for use in format for later output
    if op == add:
        op = "plus"
    elif op == sub:
        op = "minus"
    elif op == mul:
        op = "times"
    answer = raw_input("What is {0} {1} {2}?".format(num1, op, num2))
    # Checking answer and updating score
    if answer == question:
        print "Well done {0}! You got that right!".format(usr_name)
        score += 1
    else:
        pass
    no_questions += 1
```

It's part of a project I'm doing at school. When I pass this loop however the last if statement is returning True whatever the inputs are. Is my code wrong or is this a python law which I have not come across? Many thanks.

Comment: Look at the two values in the if statement and look where they originally get set.

Comment: @MatthewC, you've edited your question to remove the error that three answers provided. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even after you fix the real_answer bug, your code wont work.

raw_input returns a string, but you compare it to an integer - you need :

```
 answer = int(raw_input("What is {0} {1} {2}?".format(num1, op, num2)))
```

P.S. when someone has pointed out a bug, it is not great form to edit your question to remove the bug, it means that when other people read the question, their answers look wrong. The right thing to do is to upvote the right answer, and if you can tick the answer to accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your `real_answer` variable always equals `question` because you set them equal to one another in this line of code.

```
real_answer = question
```

Then you compare them here, without ever having changed them.

```
if real_answer == question:
```

Comment: annoyingly the OP has now edited the question to remove the bug ! but left no comment  - so it looks to any reader now that you are seeing things :-(

Comment: there is also a raw_input issue - as i have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here you set them to the same value:

```
real_answer = question
```

And you never change `real_answer,` so of course when you test it later, it is still equal to `question`.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
real_answer = question
```

then a few lines later

```
if real_answer == question:
```

Of course it is true. You set it so yourself.

... and now you've edited it so your code doesn't reproduce the stated problem any more.